# Import data from a Pandas dataset to another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas datasets:

```
import pandas
csv1 = pandas.read_csv('test1')
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('test2')
```

How to import datas from `csv2` to `csv1` according  to `csv1`'s `type` field?

---

Example:

```
#csv1
index type
1     0
2     0
3     2
4     1

#csv2
type blah
0    abc
1    def
2    ghi
```

Then the output should be:

```
index type blah
1     0    abc
2     0    abc
3     2    ghi
4     1    def
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
print (df)
   index  type blah
0      1     0  abc
1      2     0  abc
2      3     2  ghi
3      4     1  def
```

If want add only one column faster is [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['blah'] = df1['type'].map(df2.set_index('type')['blah'])
print (df1)
   index  type blah
0      1     0  abc
1      2     0  abc
2      3     2  ghi
3      4     1  def
```